# Datepicker style dont work

Tags: c#, wpf, datepicker, calendar, styles

I've written the following style

```
<Window x:Class="Wpf_ViewModelbased1.MainWindow"
        xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml/presentation"
        xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml"
        xmlns:sys="clr-namespace:System;assembly=mscorlib"
        DataContext="{Binding Source={StaticResource ViewModelLocator}, Path=MainVm}"
        Title="MainWindow" Height="350" Width="525">
    <Window.Resources>
        <!--Datepicker-->
        <Style TargetType="{x:Type DatePicker}">
            <Setter Property="Template">
                <Setter.Value>
                    <ControlTemplate TargetType="{x:Type DatePicker}">
                        <Border BorderBrush="Black" BorderThickness="1">
                            <Grid x:Name="PART_Root" >
                                <Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
                                    <ColumnDefinition Width="*" />
                                    <ColumnDefinition Width="Auto" />
                                </Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
                                <Grid.RowDefinitions>
                                    <RowDefinition/>
                                    <RowDefinition/>
                                </Grid.RowDefinitions>
                                <DatePickerTextBox x:Name="PART_TextBox" HorizontalContentAlignment="Center" BorderBrush="{TemplateBinding BorderBrush}" BorderThickness="{TemplateBinding BorderThickness}" Padding="{TemplateBinding Padding}" VerticalContentAlignment="Center" IsReadOnly="True" Grid.Row="1"/>
                                <Button x:Name="PART_Button" Grid.Row="0">
                                    <Button.Style>
                                        <Style TargetType="{x:Type Button}">
                                            <Setter Property="Template">
                                                <Setter.Value>
                                                    <ControlTemplate TargetType="{x:Type Button}">
                                                        <Image x:Name="buttonImage" Height="35" Width="35" HorizontalAlignment="center" Source="C:\Users\00027887\Documents\Visual Studio 2015\Projects\RelWA\RelWA\Resources\datepickerincon.png"/>
                                                    </ControlTemplate>
                                                </Setter.Value>
                                            </Setter>
                                        </Style>
                                    </Button.Style>
                                </Button>
                                <Popup x:Name="PART_Popup" StaysOpen="False" AllowsTransparency="True">
                                    <CalendarItem x:Name="PART_CalendarItem">
                                        <CalendarItem.Style>
                                            <Style TargetType="{x:Type CalendarItem}">
                                                <Setter Property="Template">
                                                    <Setter.Value>
                                                        <ControlTemplate TargetType="{x:Type CalendarItem}">
                                                            <Calendar SelectedDate="{x:Static sys:DateTime.Today}">
                                                                <Calendar.Background>
                                                                    <LinearGradientBrush EndPoint="0.5,1" StartPoint="0.5,0">
                                                                        <GradientStop Color="Turquoise" Offset="0.7"/>
                                                                        <GradientStop Color="White"/>
                                                                        <GradientStop Color="green" Offset="1"/>
                                                                    </LinearGradientBrush>
                                                                </Calendar.Background>
                                                            </Calendar>
                                                        </ControlTemplate>
                                                    </Setter.Value>
                                                </Setter>
                                            </Style>
                                        </CalendarItem.Style>
                                    </CalendarItem>
                                </Popup>
                            </Grid>
                        </Border>
                    </ControlTemplate>
                </Setter.Value>
            </Setter>
        </Style>
    </Window.Resources>
    <Grid>
        <DatePicker Width="100" Height="75"/>
    </Grid>
</Window>
```

In desinger window everything looks like expected:

[image]

But when i debug the application:

[image]

I don't have a clue why.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

When a `DatePicker` is visualized, its `OnApplyTemplate` method is called. If you spy that method you will find this piece of code:

```
this._popUp = (base.GetTemplateChild("PART_Popup") as Popup);
if (this._popUp != null)
{
    this._popUp.AddHandler(UIElement.PreviewMouseLeftButtonDownEvent, new MouseButtonEventHandler(this.PopUp_PreviewMouseLeftButtonDown));
    this._popUp.Opened += new EventHandler(this.PopUp_Opened);
    this._popUp.Closed += new EventHandler(this.PopUp_Closed);
    this._popUp.Child = this._calendar;
    if (this.IsDropDownOpen)
    {
        this._popUp.IsOpen = true;
    }
}
```

As you can see, the `Child` property of your "**PART_Popup**" is always overwritten with a calendar control which is a private field of the `DatePicker` itself. So it is unuseful to specify a child for the `Popup` in your `ControlTemplate`. Just leave it empty, i.e. with no child.

For setting a calender style, instead, just use the `CalendarStyle` property:

```
<DatePicker Width="100" Height="75">
    <DatePicker.CalendarStyle>
        <Style TargetType="{x:Type Calendar}">
            <Setter Property="Background">
                <Setter.Value>
                    <LinearGradientBrush EndPoint="0.5,1" StartPoint="0.5,0">
                        <GradientStop Color="Turquoise" Offset="0.7"/>
                        <GradientStop Color="White"/>
                        <GradientStop Color="green" Offset="1"/>
                    </LinearGradientBrush>
                </Setter.Value>
            </Setter>
        </Style>
    </DatePicker.CalendarStyle>
</DatePicker>
```

I hope it can help you with your issue.